# spark-submit: command not found

Tags: bash, macos, shell, environment-variables, fish

A very simple question:

I try to use a bash script to submit spark jobs. But somehow it keeps complaining that it cannot find `spark-submit` command.
But when I just copy out the command and run directly in my terminal, it runs fine.

My shell is fish shell, here's what I have in my fish shell config: `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

`alias spark-submit='/Users/MY_NAME/Downloads/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit'`

Here's my bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


SUBMIT_COMMAND="HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs spark-submit \
      --master $MASTER \
      --deploy-mode client \
      --driver-memory $DRIVER_MEMORY \
      --executor-memory $EXECUTOR_MEMORY \
      --num-executors $NUM_EXECUTORS \
      --executor-cores $EXECUTOR_CORES \
      --conf spark.shuffle.compress=true \
      --conf spark.network.timeout=2000s \
      $DEBUG_PARAM \
      --class com.fisher.coder.OfflineIndexer \
      --verbose \
      $JAR_PATH \
      --local $LOCAL \
      $SOLR_HOME \
      --solrconfig 'resource:solrhome/' \
      $ZK_QUORUM_PARAM \
      --source $SOURCE \
      --limit $LIMIT \
      --sample $SAMPLE \
      --dest $DEST \
      --copysolrconfig \
      --shards $SHARDS \
      $S3_ZK_ZNODE_PARENT \
      $S3_HBASE_ROOTDIR \
      "

eval "$SUBMIT_COMMAND"
```

What I've tried:
I could run this command perfectly fine on my Mac OS X fish shell when I copy this command literally out and directly run.
However, what I wanted to achieve is to be able to run `./submit.sh -local` which executes the above shell.

Any clues please?

Comment: Insufficient data. Please show us exactly what you typed and the output including all errors (just copy/paste from your terminal). Also, what do you see if you type `ls -l ./submit.sh`? In other words is that script in your CWD?

Comment: Also, if you're running `spark-submit` via a bash script why do you need the fish alias? What purpose does it serve? How is it relevant to your question?

Comment: The output is: `./submit.sh: line 186: spark-submit: command not found`. This is what I see `ls -l submit.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myname  staff  5700 Aug 17 16:14 submit.sh`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what a fish alias is. When you run this:

```
alias spark-submit='/Users/MY_NAME/Downloads/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit'
```

You are actually doing this:

```
function spark-submit
   /Users/MY_NAME/Downloads/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit $argv
end
```

That is, you are defining a fish function. Your bash script has no knowledge of that function. You need to either put that path in your `$PATH` variable or put a similar alias command in your bash script.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't fully understand your solution: how can I put a similar alias command in my bash script? what do you mean by this?

Comment: I think what Kurtis is trying to say is that you should edit your script above to  use `/Users/MY_NAME/Downloads/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit` rather than just `spark-submit`.

Comment: Or put `spark-submit= /Users/MY_NAME/Downloads/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark‌​-submit` at the top of the script then do `SUBMIT_COMMAND="HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs $spark-submit ..."`.

Comment: Perfect! I eventually figured it out. I already switched to zsh shell now, and added these two lines and it works: `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/spark/bin` in my ~/.zshrc Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this command is added to path:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{your_own_path_where_spark_installed}/bin
```

For `mac`, open either one of these files `~/.bash`, `~/.zprofile`, `~/.zshrc` and add the command below in the file.